# Something wrong in pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.1

this my configuration:

```
#postgres.conf:

listen_addresses = 'localhost'

#pg_hba.conf:

local all postgres md5
local all appuser trust
local all devuser trust
local all all peer
```

i'm connecting in local using the C-Library `libpq`. 
My connection string is:

`host=localhost user=appuser dbname=mydbname port='5432'`

However, unless I have a .pgpass file in the home of my developer user (devuser), (the one who launches the application that is linked with libpq), my executable cannot connect, I receive the error `fe_sendauth : no password supplied`

As I said, if the .pgpass file is here, then it connects ok.

What I don't understand: I configured `local all appuser` **trust**. 
Why do I need a .pgpass file all the same?

(It's not a serious problem in itself, because later on for security measure, it will no longer be at `trust`, but `md5`, so I'll have the .pgpass file anyway. But I'd like to know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see how one might think [`listen_addresses = 'localhost'`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS) is somehow related to the authentication method `local`. But it is not. I quote [the manual on `listen_addresses`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CONNECTION-SETTINGS):

> listen_addresses (string)
>
> Specifies the **TCP/IP address(es)** on which the server is to listen for connections from client applications.

And the chapter [The `pg_hba.conf` File](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) in the manual:

> local
>
> This record matches connection attempts using **Unix-domain sockets**. Without a record of this type, Unix-domain socket connections are
>   disallowed.

Bold emphasis mine.

For connections via `localhost` (TCP/IP, local loopback) you actually need an entry for the [authentication method **`host`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) in your `pg_hba.conf` file (not for `local`).