# Access to database denied :ELEPHANTSQL on Bluemix - “No pg_hba.conf entry for host localhost, user ADMIN, database SYSTEM”

Tags: postgresql, connections, pg-hba.conf

While trying to connect to my ElephantSQL database on Bluemix using pgadmin, it throws the following error.

> ```
> Access to database denied
> The server doesn't grant access to the database: the server reports 
> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XXX.XX.XX", user "abcd", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XX.XXX.XX.XX", user "abcd", database "postgres", SSL off
>
> To access a database on a PostgreSQL server, you first have to grant primary access to the server for your client (Host Based Authentication). PostgreSQL will check the pg_hba.conf file if a pattern that matches your client address / username / database is present and enabled before any SQL GRANT access control lists are evaluated.
> ```

How can I access the pg_hba.conf file on bluemix?

[image]

Comment: x-posted to http://stackoverflow.com/q/31629438/398670

Comment: BTW, it's pgAdmin III (or just pgAdmin), not pgAdmin 111. I fixed that. And the error message in the title does not match the one in the body ...

Comment: Yes, its pgAdmin III .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On ElephantSQL shared plans, make sure that you put your database name (which is the same as your username) in the "Maintenance database" field in PGAdmin. [This is explained in the docs](http://www.elephantsql.com/docs/pgadmin.html). Right now you're trying to connect to the "postgres" database, which you don't have access to on the shared server.

Comment: Genius! Thanks for the light!

Comment: This fixed my issue, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

The error message means you are *already* accessing [`pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). There is just no line granting access for your connection attempt. At least one of your provided details (host, user, database) does not match for any line in the file.

I am not familiar with ElephantSQL, but it seems to be a database hosting service providing standard PostgreSQL. Advice in the manual should apply. Here is a related answer with more explanation and links:

- [Something wrong in pg_hba.conf](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34037/something-wrong-in-pg-hba-conf/34042#34042)

Comment: Yes, ur right. I see tht its actually seeing the `.conf`file. But, I cannot see how i could edit it. I mean, bluemix's ElephantSQL console does not give u a portal to edit these files. Is there a way to access these file ?. (I have added a screenshot of the portal- To the main Quesn)

Comment: @Betafish: According to [the online documentation of ElephantSQL](http://www.elephantsql.com/docs/index.html), there should be a connection URL visible ... You might contact the company for assistance.

Comment: It works now. I did contact the company for assistance.